# for-loop with variable vs without using a variable

Tags: javascript, flutter, loops, dart, for-loop

Typically, when iterating through a list of objects, for example in a `for...in` loop, the object is assigned to a variable first.

```dart
Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    final List<KeyValue> keyValue = [
      KeyValue(
        key: 'Name',
        value: data.name,
      ),
      KeyValue(
        key: 'Age',
        value: data.age,
      ),
      KeyValue(
        key: 'Gender',
        value: data.gender,
      ),
    ];

    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var item in keyValue)
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Text('${item.key} : ${item.value}'),
          ),
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

But what if I placed the list directly inside the loop to save the trouble of creating a variable?

```dart
Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var item in [
          KeyValue(
            key: 'Name',
            value: data.name,
          ),
          KeyValue(
            key: 'Age',
            value: data.age,
          ),
          KeyValue(
            key: 'Gender',
            value: data.gender,
          ),
        ])
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Text('${item.key} : ${item.value}'),
          ),
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

Is this **anti-pattern?** Or does the former have any **performance significance** over the latter? Because if I'm not mistaken, in **Javascript**, assigning a value to a **constant variable** may prevent it from being **recreated as a new instance**. Can someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: I think in your attempted method, you would lose access to the actual object you're looping over `keyValue`; you'd only have access to `item`.

Comment: @mykaf In this case I may not need the actual object. But the point here is to use the data directly instead of assigning it to a variable. It could also be data passed to a widget like so: `Profile(data: [.../* inline data here */...])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is less readable, and it won't buy you anything performance wise (it's quite likely that the compiler would produce the machine code equivalent of your second snippet in either case).

In either case, since the value cannot be made a constant (due to the reference to `data` [unless `data` is itself a constant]), the majority of the runtime cost (which is still tiny) is in constructing the value itself, not in assigning it to a named variable.

For that reason, it's better to go with the more readable version.